# Android's Garbage Collector appear when trying to render 3D model with Opengl ES20

Tags: android, opengl-es, garbage-collection, runtime-error, opengl-es-2.0

My app renders 3D models via opengl ES2, once at a time. When I enable textures in those model my app crashes. First, I thought that was because the texture images are large, but the truth is that they are not. For instance, in one of the models, I use four .png images of sizes 4kb, 38kb, 39kb, and 200kb respectively. Are they large? I don't think so, but reading the logcat it seems that everything comes from a memory problem:

```
08-26 02:08:13.574: I/art(10870): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1557(49KB) AllocSpace objects, 22(8MB) LOS objects, 35% free, 13MB/21MB, paused 311us total 112.465ms
```

I am new on this and this message unfortunately doesn't say anything to me. Reading out there it seems that the Garbage Collector decided to appear, but I don't know the reason. Somebody can tell me what could be the issue, or give me some hint about how to attack this kind of situation?

Thank you in advance,

JM

PS: I am using a Nexus 5x and Samsung Galaxy TAB A as testing's devices

Comment: My best guess, you are allocating the image every frame or very often than it is necessary. Otherwise, loading a PNG of few KB does not cause this issue. Also keep in mind that the image file size is different from the size loaded in the memory.

Comment: Based on your other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39178777/trying-to-load-an-osg-model-with-textures-allocated-in-textureunit1 it looks like you're rendering with OSG. It's hard to help you if you don't know where the app is crashing, especially if that's due to a misuse of OSG or somewhere else in your app.   If that happens with OSG, a stack trace would help.

Comment: That's the hard part, the logcat does not show anything useful. After a few seconds running, the screen turns black and the app stops, but the logcat does not tell anything but two or three calls of the Garbage Collector as I posted before this happens. This is the only clue I have. The only thing I know for sure is that this only occurs if I load a texture as I did in the other question ....

Comment: Hi rickyviking, I have posted another question regarding this issue, with the ideas maybe more organized, if you wanna take a look. Hopefully you have experienced something similar in the past and put me in the right direction.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185710/memory-issues-when-loading-texture-images-for-osg-models-in-android